# How to check whether a card is a credit card or debit card

Tags: android, stripe-payments

i am building an android app in which i am using stripe for payment,so in my app i only want to accept debit card.So is there any way to check whether it is a credit or debit card while creating token in android app.

Comment: I don't think so. Otherwise, stores and gas stations wouldn't ask credit or debit

Comment: Limiting to only debit cards in Stripe is pointless and would only frustrate you customers. In Stripe debit and credit cards act the same and cost the same price to process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you tokenize a credit card in Stripe, your get a Token object back as documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api#token_object). It has a `card` hash that contains the `funding` property documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api#token_object-card-funding):

> Card funding type. Can be credit, debit, prepaid, or unknown

You can use this parameter to know what type of cards the customer is using and react accordingly.

Comment: while creating token ,i am not getting the funding  property in response.

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle showing an example response and you'll see funding: http://jsfiddle.net/u0w4fo19/ It's possible the Android SDK doesn't surface `funding` but you can always retrieve it server side: https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_token

Answer (score 2):

The magnetic strips on the card have more information than just numbers.
And coming to your problem, the user always knows what card he has , so you can directly ask the user and store that information in your database.

Some info about magnetic strips 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_stripe_card

Comment: what if user intentionally put the credit card info instead of debit card.i want to stop the user from putting the cerdit card info in my app.

Comment: Dont worry about that..its the user money..I think he is extra careful and paranoid than you are dude.. :P